# Wagtail large files 403 when serve

Tags: django, nginx, wagtail

In my Wagtail project I use custom document model with specified file upload path. I'm able to upload large files to specified directory, but, when I try do serve them,there is nginx 403 forbidden error. Tried a lot of different solutions from similar questions, but nothing helped :(
[image]

Comment: Hi, how did you fix it.

Comment: Hi @vindec. It was so long ago that I don't remember which of the variable settings affected the solution to the problem, but here are the settings related to file sizes that are used now:

`WAGTAILIMAGES_MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE = 500 * 1024 * 1024
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 500 * 1024 * 1024
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 500 * 1024 * 1024
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0o644`

Comment: Thanks @unicorns4re4live for me it was the permission issue. So setting `FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS` to right value worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WAGTAILIMAGES_MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE = 500 * 1024 * 1024
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 500 * 1024 * 1024
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 500 * 1024 * 1024
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0o644
```

solved the problem